# Uniform Continuity And Monotonicity

Tags: calculus

Suppose a function $f(x)$ is monotonic (suppose increasing) on the interval $[a, b]$ then it is uniformly continuous on the interval $[a, b]$
$$$$ Now for any given $\epsilon >0$ and any $x$, $y$ belonging to $[a, b]$ as the function $f(x)$ is Integrable on $[a, b]$ so it is Integrable on $[x, y]$ also and so we can make the difference between upper sum and lower sum of a partition of $[x, y]$ less than $\epsilon$ and as the function $f(x)$ is monotonic on the interval $[a, b]$ and so it is on $[x, y]$, so the difference between upper sum and lower sum is equal to $f(y)-f(x)$ and hence $f(y)-f(x)=|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon$. So for every $\epsilon$ we can choose any $\delta$ such that whenever $|x-y|< \delta$ we have $|f(x)-f(y)|< \epsilon$ for any $x$, $y$ belonging to $[a, b]$
$$$$ Is My Proof Correct?

Comment: Is the function presumed continuous *a priori*? It need not be.

Comment: That certainly can't be true. The function might not be continuous, let alone uniformly continuous.

Comment: But by the definition of uniform Continuity it is true

Comment: @user728159 you should state clearly what are your hypotheses and what you would like to prove.

Comment: I am trying to prove that the function is uniformly continuous

Comment: What are your hypotheses then?

Answer (score 2):

This is false as stated: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}  x & x < 1\\
                                               x+1 & x \ge 1\\
                                \end{cases}$$

is monotonically increasing on $[0,2]$ but not continuous, let alone uniformly continuous.

If we assume $f$ is continuous, then the compactness of $[a,b]$ (without monotonicity) will be enough to make $f$ *uniformly* continuous on $[a,b]$.